# Skype crashes on logon

Tags: crash, skype

Something I cannot understand, Skype crashes when it logs to my profile.
I have uninstalled and deleted all related files and  folder I can find.
I've ran processmonitor to see what is happening, but there's 6000 records.
I have noticed that settings are stored here ->

C:\Users...\AppData\Local\Packages\Microsoft.SkypeApp_kzf8qxf38zg5c\LocalCache\Roaming\Microsoft\Skype for Store

and there is a log folder, is there a way to enable log file for skype

I've tried with the regular skype application and skype APP, but this is the same, when it logs it simply crashes.
Nevertheless it works on my laptop.

Running under Windows 10 21H1 and skype latest version 15.68.96.0

Comment: The latest version of Desktop Skype is 8.x  . I have this working fine on two Windows 10 Pro machines, both V21H1.  Maybe uninstall any version of Skype in Program and Features, and the Skype App (Start, Settings, Apps).  Restart and install the current Desktop Skype and see if that works.

Comment: I did that many many time, and it fails, it seems to crash when connection is established.

Comment: It fails how exactly?  If you want more than “perform a repair install answer” your going to need to provide more information

Comment: I did all what could do a standard user with repair reinstall and so on. The best would be that a log file would be produced and examined.

Answer (score 0):

> Skype crashes when it logs to my profile. I have uninstalled and
> deleted all related files and folder I can find. I [uninstalled /
> reinstalled] many many times, and it fails, it seems to crash when
> connection is established.

The best thing now (given your work above) is a Windows 10 Repair Install.  This is generally and easy and straightforward process. Read through the 3 options carefully and start with Keep Everything and see if that works.

Go to the Media Creation Link:

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10

Windows 10 is running, so click on the Download button (not Upgrade Button) and select Run.
If the Repair will not run as per above, use the Download button to create a USB Windows Installation key,
then run Setup on the USB Key.

This will launch the Repair and proceed normally.  There are 3 ways to proceed, according to the severity of the error.

(1) Keep Everything: Best if it works and your computer comes back just the way you had set it up except repaired.  Always have a backup, but generally nothing will be lost.

(2) Keep Data: Necessary if the operating system damage is extensive. Keeps the User Profile and makes software install quite easy. Always have a backup, but data is not usually lost.

(3) Keep Nothing: Deletes the User Profile and all else and is essentially a fresh install.  Be certain you have backed up all your data. "Keep Nothing" is necessary if the User Profile is damaged, because broken User Profiles cannot be repaired and it is generally easier to back up and start over if the User Profile is damaged. It depends on the precise situation.

Comment: Sorry, those methods are too harsh. I cannot afford to loose anything related to other apps because of skype. i've been using PC for 30 years and I always have recovered situations by hacking files or database registry
I did already   sfc /scannow -> 0 errors and  DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /ScanHealth  -> 0 issues*

Comment: Repair Install is not harsh. I have done numerous. Keep Everything does just that - it keeps everything . I have never lost a thing with the first method. If more is wrong, then backups are in order.

Comment: I have the feeling this is a software bug that reinstall will not help. I have a "duplicate account" that I have juste deleted now, I hope this will help.

Comment: Repair Install first is NOT reinstall. Then second, it has the ability to fix everything except Profile damage. If you think you have profile damage you are best to back up and use Option 3 above.

Comment: How do you know this will work ? I cannot take the risk this PC has a lot of software installed since 2014 and are more important than Skype. Microsoft does not offer any solution nor log files, so I decided to delete it forever and use Skype under Edge (web.skype.com) and this is fine by me.

Comment: I have done repair installs and never lost anything using the Keep Everything option.